# Routing issues in rendering AngularJS components from Angular2 routes

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angularjs-routing, angular2-upgrade

I have a Hybrid(Angular1 and Angular2) repo which having mix of Angular1 and Angular2 routers. Followed the sample from https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b#.1hmxbfijw.,
 But when I try to use AngularJS component (in the example `<messages>` )component inside Angular2 Component (in the example `<settings>` ) which is rendered from Angular2 routing, I was getting a blank page.. So downgraded the ng2Root comp in ng1 context. as suggested here
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12965

So After that the routing strategy stopped working.. here is the repo which describes the problem.

https://github.com/a5hik/ng1ng2

PS: When I do after bootstrap `platformRef.injector.get(Router).initialNavigation();` I can able to navigate Angular2 routing (in the example `\settings`) page directly from the browser, but not the other pages are working. which is the rest of the AngularJS routing are not working.

Environment:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 7.0.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.5
@angular/compiler: 2.4.5
@angular/core: 2.4.5
@angular/forms: 2.4.5
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.5
@angular/upgrade: 2.4.5
@angular/router: 3.4.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.5
@angular/platform-server: 2.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.5
@ngtools/webpack: 1.2.4
```